# Continuity correction for Pearson and McNemar's chi-square test

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, yates-correction

I think this is a rather basic question, but I just realize that I don't quite understand the term continuity correction.

I use R and found the same syntax `correct=TRUE` for both `chisq.test` and `mcnemar.test`. Are they referring to different continuity correction method?

I have heard of the yate's continuity for pearson chi-square test is not very popular now as it may "over-adjust" the result, then how about that for McNemar's chi-square test?

Thanks.

Comment: The wiki article might help out:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another reason that continuity corrections for contingency tables have gone out of fashion is that they only make a noticeable difference when the cell counts are small, and modern computing power has made it feasible to calculate 'exact' p-values for such tables.

Exact tests for 2×2 tables for **R** are provided by the [exact2x2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/) package written by [Michael Fay](http://www.niaid.nih.gov/about/organization/dcr/BRB/staff/Pages/michael.aspx). There's an accompanying [vignette about the exact McNemar's test and matching confidence intervals](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exactMcNemar.pdf).

Comment: (+1) I discovered this package only recently. It looks interesting.

Comment: His paper about it got into *Biostatistics*: http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biostatistics/kxp050