# Mann-Kendall trend test, z-Transformation of test statistic, Why is the mean +/-1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, trend, kendall-tau

I have been looking into the Mann-Kendall test for detecting monotonic trends in my data. I have been following the introduction on this site [here](http://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/Design_Trend_Mann_Kendall.htm).

It all looks quite plausible to me. 
However, I got a bit stuck with the z-Transformation of the S value.

[image: z-Transformation of test statistic]

Why is the mean of S equal to 1?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume no ties (because it simplifies the explanation, without changing the reason for the $\pm 1$).

The number of pairs will be $n(n-1)/2$. The count of the number of increases ($x_j>x_i$ when $j>i$) will be a non-negative integer (which will not exceed the number of pairs). Call this $n_+$ (and correspondingly, $n_-$ will be the number of decreases).

In large samples under the null hypothesis, $n_+$ would be approximately normal with mean $\mu_0=n(n-1)/4$ and known standard deviation.

As is often the case when using a normal approximation for a discrete variate, we can consider using a [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction) when approximating $n_+$. If you're unfamiliar with continuity corrections, see the detailed discussion of the continuity correction [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213966/why-does-the-continuity-correction-say-the-normal-approximation-to-the-binomia/213995#213995), which includes numerous pictures.

This correction would take the form of moving *half a unit* toward the mean under the null, so it would be $n_+-\frac12$ if $n_+>\mu_0$ and $n_++\frac12$ if $n_+<\mu_0$.

Now note that $S=n_+-n_- = n_+-[n(n-1)/2-n_+] = 2(n_+ - \mu_0$). That is, 
the number of increases minus the number of decreases will change in steps of $2$ (twice the steps for $n_+$) and will centered at 0 (when the null is true).

A corresponding continuity correction for $S$ will move $2\times \frac12$ toward its mean ($0$). That is it will subtract $1$ when $S>0$ and add $1$ when $S<0$.

Also see the discussion of the adjustment in the McNemar test [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219179/why-yates-correction-in-mcnemars-test-subtract-1/219222#219222) which is a somewhat similar situation.